# Can Cloud Firestore onSnapshot() only trigger on changes, and not get the initial state?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) says:

> You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

I just want my listener to fire when the data changes. I don't want it to fire when the app loads, to get the initial state of the data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would love this feature!

Answer (score 11):

Firestore listeners don't work that way.  You will always be delivered the document(s) relevant to the fetch or query, then updates after that for as long as the listener remains added.  There is no mode to receive deltas only.

If you want to receive only certain data, you might want to figure out how to query for it, for example, by adding a timestamp field and having the client only query for documents that have changed since some prior time.

Comment: It would be great if the ability to ignore the initial state was there. In my apps, I am syncing data with Firebase and I am storing it in CoreData for further use by my app. It is quite annoying that upon the app's launch I get all the data from the listener, even the one I already have stored. I now need to find a way to ignore this first launch. Are we guaranteed that there will always be 1 response with all local data (initial state) which will NOT contain any new info from the server?  If so, I could ignore exactly one response from the listener to achieve the functionality which I want.

Comment: You can't ignore data.  You could instead construct a query that only returns the data you want.  If you can't construct such a query, then you're out of luck.

Comment: thank you for your response. Subscribing to updates after timestamp is not feasible in my case. Maybe my setup is wrong and you could advise me how to correct it. I have a theory test app and I want to store user’s progress. When they take a test, I wish to store the test log so that I can then reconstruct their actual progress. We could instead store one file with the overall statistics, but I am concerned about the bandwidth. Also, I am worried that a single file with up to date progress would go over the field size limit.

Comment: nevermind - there is a property "isFromCache" which allows me to easily ignore any reads coming from local cache regardless of whether it is the first launch or not. It is exactly what I need.

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options

Comment: It would be nice to get an Etag along with a read, then next time you read the same collection, you can provide your Etag as "this is what I have already" and if there's a newer Etag in Firestore, it sends only the deltas in the next query.

Comment: Thanks for your official support on SO, Mr. Doug. I have a question regarding your statement "Firestore listeners don't work that way"... The documentation states that this implicit behavior is designed for the convenience of populating the UI using the initial state. In that case, the user ought to be given an option whether to receive the initial state or not, right? A field such as `ListenerOptions.getInitialState()` and `ListenerOptions.ignoreInitialState()` would make the `onSnapshot()` method more flexible, just like 'SetOptions.merge()'! Is this a reasonable request, Firebaser?  :D

Comment: @varun Sure, you are always free to file a feature request with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh, alright. I'll file it some time soon!  :)

Comment: @varun Did you eventually a feature request for this feature?

Comment: @arcety Hi there. I think I did file one back then... but I'm not sure what happened because there is no request tracker or feedback ID... Just in case, I've sent the same feature request again today, thanks for letting me know. Look forward to this handy feature!  :)

Comment: @varun Ha, great, thanks! Hope they take it into consideration. Would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 9):

After reading the first and second solution, I have made a solution that seems to work.
First you initialize a variable to `true` and inside the `onSnapshot()` method you check if this variable is `true`, if it is, you change it to `false`, and on else you write your retrieving data algorithm. Something like this:

```
var initState = true;

let observer = records.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {

    console.log(`Received doc snapshot`);

    if (initState) {
        initState = false;
    } else {
        if (!docSnapshot.docChanges().empty) {     
            docSnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
               //Write here wahtever you want

            });
        }
    }

}, err => {
    console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

Comment: Note: This solution is very very superficial, all it is doing is ignoring the first fetch of data using an (if...else) statement. The only solution to the OP's question is to wait for the firestore team to give us an API which can make the initial snapshot optional.

Comment: 3 years later. do we have this already ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Whenever you use onSnapshot, an initial call is made to get the data immediately and after that changes are listened.

But you can handle the logic within it to detect wether it was an initial call or updates trigger using the following properties provided by the firebase.

```
  db
  .collection("pets")
    .doc(petId)
    .onSnapshot(
      snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.data()
          // either edit, update or delete
          if (snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites) { 
            if (snapshot.exists) {
              // edit or create logic
            }
            else{
             // delete logic
            }
        }
      
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Firestore listeners loads by their own order and the "onSnapshot" event must always execute first on initial state. But, you can handle that behavior adding a initial state variable like:

```
var initState = true;
db.collection('col').doc('id').onSnapshot(....
```

Then you could validate inside the function the code you dont want to run when your application starts.

```
var initState = true;
db.collection('col').doc('id').onSnapshot(....
if(!initState){ // if is not initial state
   //your code
}
```

and after the application starts up you must change initState to *false* and add a sleep/timeout function (cause it may have an unexpcted asyncronous load)

```
var initState = true;
db.collection('col').doc('id').onSnapshot(....
if(!initState){ // if is not initial state
   //your code
}

setTimeout(function () { // cause onSnapShot executes first
   initState = false;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -3):

What also worked for me was to check for the document.readystate and then choose to act on the snapshot changes. Like this -

```js
db.collection("collectionName").onSnapshot( (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.docChanges())
    if( ["loaded","interactive", "complete"].indexOf(document.readyState) >=0 ){
        <-----Your code to act on the snapshot changes---->

}
```

Based on the readystate property documentation here -
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

Comment: You reference link relates to HTML documents not Firestore documents.